# How to manually add a rule to a classification tree in R

Tags: r, tree, rpart

I have fitted two classification trees using the rpart and tree packages in R. I would like to manually add a rule to one of the fitted trees, whichever is easiest. Is there a way to do this?

Here is an example (taken from the article [A Brief Tour of the Trees and Forests](http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-brief-tour-of-the-trees-and-forests/)) of what I want to achieve:

```
library(tree)
tr = tree(frmla, data=raw)
summary(tr)
plot(tr); text(tr)
```

This is how the fitted tree would look:

[image: The fitted tree]

Now, let's say for some reason (i.e. my prior knowledge or based on another fitted tree for another set of data) I want to set the response to NM is Koc<5. Since this information is not in the training set used for fitting the above tree, how can I incorporate that into it?